# Nuget 1.6 install issue

Tags: nuget

In admin mode I uninstalled Nuget 1.5 from vs, restarted vs, then went into VS in admin mode, installed 1.6, and then restarted vs. Nuget has worked for 2 days.

Today, the package manager wont come up - it doesnt give me an error, it just wont load. If I try to uninstall it, the uninstall button is greyed out (which I assume means that the addin is in use). If I restart vs, then I can uninstall.

I have tried uninstalling Nuget and reinstalling it several times (no error messages generated)

Update:

not solved yet, but here's a link to where I show the results of running devenv/log and then try to open the package console:

[Nuget 1.5 -> 16 install issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683220/nuget-1-5-16-install-issue)

Does that help?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

NuGet unfortunately requires you to be running Visual Studio as an administrator in order to uninstall it.

This is described in the [NuGet known issues](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/known-issues) page. Just launch Visual Studio as an administrator and you should be able to uninstall it.

Comment: Hi Phil, thanks for responding. I did go in as admin, with the same results.  Any other ideas? Is there an install log that gets written somewhere that I could see what's happening?

Comment: I have put part of the log file (from running devenv/log) in the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683220/nuget-1-5-16-install-issue  - hope that helps!