# Nuget 1.5 -> 16 install issue

Tags: nuget

I am running VS2010 Ultimate, I used to have VS Web Dev 2010 Express with Nuget before: I uninstalled it before installing Ultimate.

**In admin mode** I uninstalled Nuget 1.5 from vs, **restarted vs in admin mode**, installed 1.6, and then restarted vs. Nuget worked for several days.

The next day, the package manager wont come up - it doesnt give me an error, it just wont load. If I try to uninstall it, the uninstall button is greyed out (which I assume means that the addin is in use). If I restart vs, then I can uninstall.

I have tried uninstalling Nuget and reinstalling it several times (no error messages generated)

Trying to load Package Manager Console  and the Package Manager Settings, dont launch anything.

Is there a way to install version 1.5? I've looked for a link but cannot find one.

Is there a log file I can check to see what is wrong?

This has been an extremely frustrating issue for me.

Update:

I used devenv /log, tried to open the package console.

Here's part of the log file:

225   Leaving function LoadDTETypeLib     VisualStudio 2011/12/30 21:54:45.181

226 ERROR **SetSite failed for package [NuGet.Tools.NuGetPackage, NuGet.Tools**, Version=1.6.21215.9133, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a] {5FCC8577-4FEB-4D04-AD72-D6C629B083CC} 80131509 VisualStudio 2011/12/30 21:54:45.196

227 ERROR **End package load [NuGet.Tools.NuGetPackage**, NuGet.Tools, Version=1.6.21215.9133, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a] {5FCC8577-4FEB-4D04-AD72-D6C629B083CC} 80131509 VisualStudio 2011/12/30 21:54:45.227

228 Warning **Package failed to load; error message suppressed by skip flag {5FCC8577-4FEB-4D04-AD72-D6C629B083CC}**  VisualStudio 2011/12/30 21:54:49.486

229   Entering function CVsPackageInfo::HrInstantiatePackage

Thanks!

Comment: have you read this: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/Reference/Known-Issues

Comment: Thanks for responding Daniel. Yes I have, but none of the issues applied.  I updated my post with results from vs log - hopefully that helps

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finally got it working: had to delete c:\User Data\\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config  (which was empty) and now it can load.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, nuget worked yesterday but not today with "SetSite failed for package [NuGet.Tools.NuGetPackage" in the VS log.

After a lot of trying and failing I found this page, and then the discussion at http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/284604

I followed the advice from bsparkinson there :

- Unistalled Nuget.
- Searched for nuget in %appdata% and deleted everything
- Reinstalled Nuget.

And now it works.

Comment: I had the same problem and this solution worked for me as well.

Answer (score 3):

You mentioned:

> If I try to uninstall it, the uninstall button is greyed out (which I
>   assume means that the addin is in use).

Is it greyed out even when you run VS as an admin? The button should only be greyed out if you're not running as admin.

The other thing you should do is try running the following command. You'll need to use the devenv command prompt.

```
 vsixinstaller.exe /uninstall:NuPackToolsVsix.Microsoft.67e54e40-0ae3-42c5-a949-fddf5739e7a5
```

That should uninstall the NuGet VSIX. After doing that, the following directory should be gone or empty: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft Corporation\NuGet Package Manager\\

Comment: Thanks for responding Phil! still no good. The command you gave runs fine, and the directory doesnt exist afterwards, but I'm running into the same issue: trying to load the package console or settings doesnt appear to do anything

Comment: yes, no luck there - although there are a few people who've said they are getting the same behavior